# Django. Restrict page access

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-errors

I have some custom error pages and views for them. How can I restrict access to this pages from browser directly, so if user type in address string "somesite/some_error" he won't get this page. It should be showed only when some error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of prohibiting access, can't you simple render the error page you want to display? That is, instead of the

```
render_to_result('mypage.html', {})
```

you do now, do a

```
render_to_result('error500.html', {'error': 'oops'})
```

That way you don't have explicit urls, but you do get the information out to the user.